# Transcribing a song that is sung in an Erzgebirgisch dialect

Tags: dialect, lyrics

I am looking for the lyrics to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikcmCBKXa5g
However, I have come up dry at all search results. I was wondering if anyone on here could give it a go in transcribing it. Even if it's just a few words, that would be excellent.

Comment: This may be helpful in comprehension: https://vocaroo.com/i/s1XfxMTGTlu1 . I have lowered the speed/pitch of the song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually not the right place for asking for transcriptions, but, well, as tomorrow is a national holiday in Germany:

> Glück auf, Glück auf, Glück auf!
>
> Steigt die Sonn‘ früh morgens xxxxxxxxx, 
>   schreit der Kuckuck xxxxxxxxx,
>   springt der Hase fix am Waldrand auf
>   und die Rehlein durchs Gestrüpp,
>   wird der Rucksack hurtig aufgehuckt
>   und ein Lied klingt aus der Brust
>   in der würzigen Luft xxxxx gekuckt,
>   so ein Wandern ist e[ine] Lust.
>
> Schritt im Schritt die Waldstraß' nauf
>   ein xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
>   Heut geht’s frisch den Berg xxxx nauf.
>   Ihr Leut, ist das eine Freud!
>   Drum, ihr zünftigen Wandersleut,
>   nun kommt und wandert mit
>   durch das schöne Harzgebirg!
>   Das stärkt Herz und Gemüt.
>
> Tralali tralala, tralalalala trala, tralalalala trala.

That's what I understood after about five times listening. There may be some mistakes or inaccurracies yet.

Language-wise the text is very close to standard German; just some very weak dialectal forms are used here and there.

Content-wise I think German popular/folk culture has seen higher peaks.

---

Notes:

1) "aufgehuckt" is an interesting word here. I needed quite a time to get it, as this is not in general use. However, we still have "huckepack" for carrying something on your back. "Hucke" should be a wooden device to carry something on your back, used in agriculture (in the pre-machine era).

2) A more typical place for asking for lyrics would be https://musicfans.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for that. Where is the proper place for transcriptions then? Sorry, I hadn't realized. How do you mean "I think German popular culture has seen higher peaks"?

Also, in this line, "Schritt im Schritt den Waldxxxx nauf", could this be "Schritt im Schritt den Wald(struß) nauf " , perhaps a dialectal form of Waldstraße.

Comment: Well, I meant, the text is extraordinarily silly, but even not in an entertaining way. If you are looking for more intelligent folk songs search e.g. for Zupfgeigenhansel, Biermösl Blosn, Fredl Fesl, they are either funny in a good way, or in the case of Zupfgeigenhansel revive songs of peasants directed against supressive structures in 18th century society, etc.

Comment: Waldstruß --> Waldstraße, yes, that's definitely a good suggestion.Should then be "Waldweg" in modern standard German.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have heard a lot of different German folk songs, this one mainly stuck out at me more so as a 'listening exercise', admittedly the song is catchy and has grown on me (having listened to it countless times). I will have a look at the ones you have recommended!

Comment: Here is a very famous Zupfgeigenhansel piece: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBxodBIgJrc ("Bürgerlied"; that's a song from the revolutionary mid 19th cent.) - Mind the very rare five-four time. And here is another one, this time with mildly adult content: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt_sE9S56PQ ("Papst und Sultan"). And here a lesser known Fredl Fesl song with a similar topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBjpjsZzr4k

Comment: So, last reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcrsUMQbrlA - This is quite new: "Mein Sachsen, hier bin ich geboren". This is actually a parody, but you can hardly understand this from just listening. It was created for the intro to a famous "Tatort" whodunnit "Auf einen Schlag", and the song gets interrupted by the discovery of a dead body backstage. - Perhaps you like this. The music is catchy, too.

Comment: Many thanks for the links and the help, I will have a good listen to them!

Comment: I think it's Arzgebirg not Harzgebirg. I don't get the xxxxx lyrics either, sorry